# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined

Tags: vue.js, laravel-9

[image]

hi iam tring to learn about vue-router  and i watched more than 1 tutrial but i got this error 'Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined 'and the router-link tags unclickable
here is my versions in pack json

```
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"

"devDependencies"
    "axios": "^0.27",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "vite": "^3.0.9"
},
"dependencies"
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.3"
```

app.js

```
 import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue';

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue'
import About from './components/about.vue'
import {createRouter} from 'vue-router'

import {createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'





const routes =[
{path : "/",  component :ExampleComponent  ,name : 'home'},
{path : "/about",  component : About ,name : 'about'}

]
const router =createRouter({
    el : '#app',
    history : createWebHistory,
    routes,
})

const app =createApp()
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

welcome.blade

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
        </head>
   <body>
    <div  id="app">
        <router-link to ="/">home</router-link>
        <router-link to ="/about">about</router-link>
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')

    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error yet, but the links are wrong because you're using named routes so you should use another syntax for the links in the HTML (welcome.blade):
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html#named-routes

Or remove the name attributes from your routes in app.js.

Also pay a bit more attention to indentation and whitespace as that might also throw the compiler off and might be the reason you get the error it should look like this:

```
const routes = [
    {path : "/", component: ExampleComponent, name: "home"},
    {path : "/about", component: About, name: "about"}
]
```

Hope this helps you out.